# Android Screen Size resources

Tags: android, android-screen-support

I am trying to understand screen sizes and densities and what I really need to do in order to make my multiple choice question game work on every Android screen nicely. I want my game to look the same in every screen size and density meaning no changes to the layout and good looking images.

Basically my game displays questions which are png files, and answers to choose from which are also png files. I specify each imageview size and imagebutton in dp, and the locations of these on the screen in dp. For my layout background image I just have it fill parent width and height.

So my question is why can't I just have one drawable folder with hdpi images? Therefore, the images would be scaled appropriately in dp on all screen sizes and located in the same place and look the same on every screen. And the images would look good on hdpi screens and smaller ones? Also, why can't I just have one layout folder with the same explanation?for your answers!

Comment: They do get scaled properly. You can have just one layout in the default place. I'm not sure what you mean. Post code, or better yet, screen caps.

Answer (score 0):

You can create the only one folder but the images in that must be .9.png bcoz these images stretched according to the screen. Another way is create the different size images and place them in the hdpi,mdpi,ldpi folders.

Comment: The image can be other than 9 patch png. You can use 9 patch if you want to make only a part of your png strechable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create only one folder for both ressources. But for image, if you dont want to get uggly stretched image you should create 3 image size with different dpi for each folder. Your picture will be sharper for hight dpi screen and faster for low dpi screen with a picture near the final size.